# Slow notification hub registrations

Tags: azure, push-notification, push, azure-mobile-services

I've implemented Azure Mobile App Service which uses Azure Mobile Apps .NET Server, connected it to the Notification Hub and it works.

However according to application insights my slowest calls are actually client registrations, for example:

```
PUT /push/installations/{installationId}
```

My app is deployed on azure under different resource group than notification hub. Can this be the cause?

Comment: Are these two resource groups located in the same geographical region?

Comment: Here is how it is currently. Resource group where Notification hub is, is located in South Central US, while Notification Hub is located in North Europe.  Resource group where mobile app is deployed is located in North Europe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource Group is just a container that holds the related Azure resources, and it would stores metadata about the resources, so the location for a resource group determines the data center for storing the metadata of the resources. Details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview).

> PUT /push/installations/{installationId}

This is the build-in endpoint for the mobile client to create / update the registration with the installation model. The server side code would be similar to the `PutInstallation` method under [NotificationInstallationsController.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/04d75cadc137cc478f98edfa1fa5b868e5548dfd/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Notifications/Controllers/NotificationInstallationsController.cs).

As you commented that the data center for hosting your Notification Hub is North Europe. You need to check the location of your App Service plan for running your mobile app. Details about Azure App Service plan, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview).

I would recommend you scale up your app service plan to a higher tier to check this issue. Also, you could try to make your Notification Hub and Mobile App under the same data center to narrow this issue. Additionally, you could provide the detailed comparison between the requests trace logging in your application insights for us to troubleshoot this issue.